# Escuchar desde diferente puerto SOCKET

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente programa:

Servidor

```
    import java.io.IOException; 
import java.net.DatagramPacket; 
import java.net.DatagramSocket; 


public class Professor {


  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        try{
        DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(1234);
        byte[] receive = new byte[65535];
         System.out.println("Esperant rebré missatges");

        DatagramPacket DpReceive = null;
        {
            DpReceive = new DatagramPacket(receive, receive.length);
            ds.receive(DpReceive);

            System.out.println("Alumne:" + data(receive));
            System.out.println("");

            System.out.println("Professor: Missatge rebut.Enviat la resposta a l'alumne");     

        }
     } catch (IOException e) 
        {      
            e.printStackTrace();    
        }

    }
    public static StringBuilder data(byte[] a)
    {
        if (a == null)
            return null;
        StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        while (a[i] != 0)
        {
            ret.append((char) a[i]);
            i++;
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

La clase cliente.

```
   import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;


public class Alumne {

   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        try{   // Creant socket datagrama
        DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket();
        InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        byte buf[] = null;

        {
            System.out.println("Comunicant al profesor que ja he acabat la practica..");
                  // Enviant missatge
            String inp="Ja tinc la practica acabada";
            System.out.println("");
            buf = inp.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket DpSend =
                  new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, ip, 1234);
            ds.send(DpSend);


            System.out.println("Esperant resposta del profesor....");
                // Rebent resposta



        }
    }     catch (IOException e) { 

      e.printStackTrace();  
}
    }
}
```

Tengo dos dudas.

Pero la más importante es:

Como puedo hacer que professor ( servidor) use el puerto 5555
Y el cliente "Alumno" use el puerto 5554 y que se puedan escuchar? No lo consigo de ninguna forma.

mil gracias!

Comment: Que probaste hacer? Lo intentaste? Buscaste la documentación de alguna de las clases que usas?

Comment: @fredyfx no es frances.. es catalán.

Comment: @Klaimmore he probado con InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 5555);      
        DatagramSocket datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket(addr);

Comment: disculpa la falta de conocimiento :D

Comment: @fredyfx y en cuanto a página no sé a que te refieres.

Comment: @Klaimmore he modificado el código he quitado los while mejor por try y catch.

Comment: @MontseMkd disculpa, sucede que en repetidas ocasiones he visto personas que pasaban por un tutorial en francés, u otro idioma (desconocía la escritura del catalán) y solicitaban ayuda, por eso te pregunté si podías compartir el enlace del sitio. Me alegra mucho que hayas solucionado el problema :D recuerda marcar tu respuesta como aceptada en las siguientes 22 horas. Sigue desarrollando con todo el power 2.0!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En `Professor` tienes:

```
DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(1234);
```

El [javadoc de ese constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#DatagramSocket(int)) especifica:

> Constructs a datagram socket and binds it to the specified port on the
>   local host machine

Esto quiere decir que el servidor escucha en dicho puerto.

---

En `Alumne` tienes:

```
DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket();
```

El [javadoc de ese otro constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#DatagramSocket()) especifica:

> Constructs a datagram socket and binds it to any available port on the
>   local host machine.

Por lo que escucha en cualquier puerto disponible.

---

Solo estas enviando datos en `Alumne` y al hacerlo lo haces con:

```
InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
DatagramPacket DpSend =
                  new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, ip, 1234);
```

Pero, el [javadoc de ese constructor de DatagramPacket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramPacket.html#DatagramPacket(byte[],%20int,%20java.net.InetAddress,%20int)) dice:

> Constructs a datagram packet for sending packets of length `length` to
>   the specified port number on the specified host. The length argument
>   must be less than or equal to `buf.length`.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - buf - the packet data.
> - length - the packet length.
> - address - the destination address.
> - port - the destination port number.

Luego, la aplicacion de tu pregunta:

> Como puedo hacer que professor ( servidor) use el puerto 5555 Y el
>   cliente "Alumno" use el puerto 5554 y que se puedan escuchar?

Es directa, basta cambiar los puertos de escucha de los sockets y especificar los puertos correctos en los packets.

Comment: gracias por los detalles!! Ojala lo hubiera encontrado antes xD!!!

Comment: Al final viendo ejemplos, leyendo acabe entendiedolo. Pero tu forma de explicarlo lo hace mucho más sencillo